# deny ssh from all except 1 IP and allow root from everything

Tags: linux, ssh, root, sshd

I was able to deny ssh to my server from all ip addresses except 1 by entering

```
sshd: all
```

in /etc/hosts.deny

and

```
sshd: x.x.x.x
```

in /etc/hosts.allow (ip hidden)

but I want to add an exception that allows root to log from everywhere.
Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: Right. Why close a door when you can tear down a wall?

Comment: You do realize that if anyone is trying to break in via ssh, the first login username they will try is root? So... your deny all means absolutely nothing? Most common practice I know is root - deny logon. The only way to get root is via sudo, or su root after you login using your normal account.

Comment: The answer should be in `AllowUser` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :-) ... but I don't have the time to write more now and moreover I think it is dangerous and deprecable to give direct root access from remote. An hacker or a malicious software can always find a way to break into your system but why to roll out a red carpet for it?

Comment: @Op, Please explain your reasoning. What you have asked for is dangerous, so it sounds like an X -> Y problem (ie, you have problem X, but ask for a solutiuon Y, when Y is not be the proper solution at all; only by analyzing the X can we come up with a better Y).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

But before I list it, I will reply to your pre judgment comments young fellows:

1. I am not trying to create a secure login.
2. what I am trying to do is to force users (other than root) to login to my device via a specific server with a specific IP address, which can be called a JUMP SERVER. why? because I am tracking their command history and to know what and when they are logging in. why not use LDAP/RADIUS? because my servers are running on a vendors re-configured OS that does not support the feature. how am I tracking the users history? I am creating a script that everytime someone ssh to my servers it will send me the username+time of login and same for logout.
3. And there you go , a short version of what I am trying to do. Now please if you have any questions do not hesitate to ask.

the answer is the below :

```
vi /etc/security/access.conf
```

and add the below:

```
+:root:ALL
+:ALL:x.x.x.x
-:ALL:ALL
```

considering x.x.x.x is the only IP address that you want to allow all users to login from.

Then  `vi /etc/pam.d/sshd`
and amend the below:

```
account required pam_access.so
```